# How to use lightning base components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to use [lightning base components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_overview.htm) in some components but I only got basic html component in my page. 
For example I add this button :

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Précédent" onclick="{!c.previousPage}"/>
```

It is the only lightning base element in my component, maybe I have to insert it into a special element, like a container ?

My Salesforce org is in spring 17.

Here is the kind of button I got : [image] instead of button with slds design.

Edit : I try differents browsers but I always get the same result.

Comment: Salut dou. What do you mean by basic html component? Can you post a picture?

Comment: Hi, I mean that in my browser, I only get html element like a basic button with no design, but with the lightning base element `lightning:button` I should see the slds design directly applied to the button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are testing in an app container then you will need to extend with force:slds

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Précédent" onclick="{!c.previousPage}"/>
</aura:application>
```

And if you are using in community builder or app builder or lightning out the styling is automatically taken care

Comment: Great thank you ! This the first time I use the lightning base components and the slds design is now applied to all my elements, that's very cool . Thank you for the clarification.